# After installing ubuntu 14.4 my computer goes to blank screen with curser then black screen with login line then blank screen again

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, login

Thats it,has worked on system before. I had a agp Video card when it was working I installed a *new Asus ENGT220 1Gb video card* with a fresh install of system, now I can't get pass user name without it looping and then stopping on blank screen with blinking cursor. I have to hardboot the computer to get it to respond again. I had it working with *generic video drivers* but was very slow. I installed the working drivers for video card and after that I can't get to login screen.

Comment: I am not sure but this might help - if in a log in loop you will need to work in Terminal Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F6 -sign in with your user name and password; read down the link for installation without X from the console [driver issue](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)